# Can't populate NSMenu from document controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I've a MainMenu.xib and a MyDocument.xib. I need to dynamically populate some NSMenuItem's from my document controller but I'm at a loss on how to get to it from MainMenu.xib.

I've tried adding an NSObject to MainMenu.xib and make it an instance of my document controller but I can't populate the NSMenuItem's from the NSArrayController I have on the controller.

Should I just do this in code or is there another way of tackling this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MyDocument.m:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *) aController
```

try this:

```
NSMenu * mainMenu = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu];
```

See **Introduction to Application Menus and Pop-up Lists** in Apple docs for more